# Renaming a table that is a foreign key in another table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, migration

I had a table neighboorhoods and a table schools with a neighboorhood_id field.

When I saw that it was misspelled I wanted to change the name to the correct form.

First I used phpStorm's name refactor tool and changed the model to Neighborhood, then I added the $table = 'neighboorhood'.

Then I made a migration to rename the table, deleted the $table property and everything is working fine.

I thought it was going to throw an error because the foreign key constraint was created this way:

```
$table->foreign('neighboorhood_id')->references('id')->on('neighboorhoods')->onDelete('cascade');
```

And now it works without having to update it to:

```
$table->foreign('neighborhood_id')->references('id')->on('neighborhoods')->onDelete('cascade');
```

Why didn't I have to modify the constraint? I checked the constraint in the database and now it's pointing to neighborhoods table instead of neighboorhoods.

Answer (score 1):

I've also had such a situation. Apparently InnoDB doesnt use the table name as a reference to the constraint: it uses some internal identity instead (not sure about other database types).

Think about it as an `ID`, which stays the same when  the `name` of the table changes.

However, the [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/rename-table.html) say something different, so dropping and creating a new foreign key would definitely be a good thing to do.

> Foreign keys that point to the renamed table are not automatically updated. In such cases, you must drop and re-create the foreign keys in order for them to function properly.